# Fn traits look like function signatures when used for trait bounds. Why?

Tags: rust, closures, traits

Currently I'm learning closures of rust. Here's an example code:

```rust
struct Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<u32>,
}
```

What I don't quite understand is the type annotation syntax in the above where clause.

So, rust doesn't have a "function type", and it uses Fn trait family for the same purpose. I understand this, but the syntax explanation is still missing as far as I know.

I tried running this command in my terminal `rustup doc core::ops::Fn`, and found the below sentence(not an explanation I'm looking for though) like this:

> Also of note is the special syntax for `Fn` traits (e.g. `Fn(usize, bool) -> usize`). Those interested in the technical details of this can refer to [the relevant section in the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html).

I also followed the link to Rustonomicon, but I couldn't find something like a definition of this syntax.

Can someone help me to understand this? (Or the rust documentation is missing this simple explanation?)

Comment: [Closures: Anonymous Functions that Capture Their Environment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) (The Rust Programming Language)

Comment: Note that Rust does have a function type, it's `fn()`. But closures aren't of that type. Instead, each closure has its own type specific to the particular closure.

Comment: Thanks, [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342). I believe you mean the function pointer type that are implicitly coerced. I haven't reached to the point in my learning journey, but it will get clearer as I progress.

Comment: Well there needs to be _some_ kind of syntax to write the Fn traits.
Since functions can take an arbitrary amount of argument (depending on the function's signature), `Fn<Param, Return>` would not cut it, because other functions may have more than one parameter, like `Fn<Param1, Param2, Return>`. The language _could_ have been designed to take the approach of `Fn<Params, Return>` and require `Params` to be a tuple, but it was not. Hence the current syntax for function traits.

Comment: @RichardNeumann actually it was designed to take `Params` as a  tuple. Look at the [definition `pub trait Fn<Args> where Args: Tuple`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) `Fn(Param1, Param2) -> Return` is just syntax sugar.

Comment: @cafce25 Really? I've never seen this syntax? Was is altered along the way of Rust's development? UPDATE: Interesting. I didn't know it like that.

Comment: As far as I know it's always been that way, but the syntax sugar has been there as well.

Comment: I just noticed that you can use `T: Fn<(u32,), Output = u32>,` with `#![feature(unboxed_closures)]` on nightly.

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are asking. Are you asking why this syntax doesn't work with your own traits?

Comment: In general, I can use traits in type annotations like this: `T: SomeTrait`. But when it comes to `Fn` trait family, it looks quite different: `T: Fn(u32) -> u32`. I wondered why. I couldn't find a clear explanation anywhere. Does this clarification make sense?

Comment: Why this was made? So they look more like functions. Why this is possible? Because the compiler special-cases them.